# Where are the options to control a Button's background?

Tags: android

I would have thought that there would be a variety of options in connection with a button's background from an image, for example the image could be tiled, or stretched or centred etc etc, but when I list a button's methods I can't see anything. Now I'm suspecting that it could be a two stage process, perhaps getting some kind of view first and then using a method of that view. Or maybe there is simply no control whatsoever concerning a button background. Please advise.

Comment: You probably want to use a Drawable. See an example for tiling here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9771293/752320

Comment: I don't think I understand what you want. But have you tried using a ImageButton, or even a ImageView(that you use as a button)?
I think you'll get more control that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that any `View`'s background is something that fills the area covered by that `View`, so you can't have it centered.

Stretching the the default behaviour, that's why a [state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) of [9-patches](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#NinePatch) the the best thing to use for `Button`'s background.

If you want tiled background, you may use [XML Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) with `tileMode="repeat"`. See also other kinds of `Drawable`s on this site. You can for example make something that feels like centered background image using [Inset `Drawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Inset).

And finally the functions are there: [`setBackgroundDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) and [`setBackgroundResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29).